# How can reselect createSelector be able to be treated as the data or array when it returns a function?

Tags: reselect

When we use the npm package [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect) (with React), we may do

```
export const someData = createSelector(
  objs,
  (objs) => {
    // ...
});
```

and I think `someData` is actually a function?  But inside of our Component's `.jsx` file, we could show it as:

```
{someData[0].countThumbUp}
```

so it is somewhat strange, when `someData` is a function, but we can somehow treat it as an array.  How does it work?

Comment: Reselect is typically used for selecting (hence the name) from a state tree object BEFORE being passed into a react component. It is a function which you must call prior to passing the returned value into the react component as a property, so you would not be referencing the function inside your component at all, it would simply receive the data returned by the selector as a prop. It possible that `someData` inside your component is actually an array returned by a previous call to the selector of the same name. Although without seeing the rest of the component code I can't say for sure

Comment: `createSelector` returns a `Selector` (can be seen here: https://github.com/reactjs/reselect/blob/master/src/index.d.ts#L3) which is a function. So `{someData[0].countThumbUp}` shouldn't be possible. Can you show more of your code?